# VueJS multiply value of two inputs into another input when the component is mounted?

Tags: vue.js

I have three inputs and I need to multiply the values of the first two into the third one when the component is mounted. I can do this with vanilla JS and jquery, but with Vue I need to take another approach and I do not know how. How can I achieve this?

HTML

```
<input class="1" type="text" value="2"></input>
<input class="2" type="text" value="5"></input>
<input class="3" type="text" value="0"></input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use lifecycle hook, so when component is mounted first two fields will sum for third. template:

```html
    <input class="1" type="text" v-model="fieldOne"></input>
    <input class="2" type="text" v-model="fieldTwo"></input>
    <input class="3" type="text" v-model="fieldThree"></input>
```

V-model will link inputs to properties, described there, then you just need to calculate field in mounted hook:

```js
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: () => ({
            fieldOne: 10,
            fieldTwo: 20,
            fieldThree: 0
        }),
        mounted() {
            this.fieldThree = this.fieldOne + this.fieldTwo;
        }
    })
```

More about lifecycle hooks you can read [here](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%E2%80%94-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed properties https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html
I write code below to sum with computed and v-model

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    num1: 10,
    num2: 20
  },
  computed: {
    sum(){
        return +this.num1 + +this.num2
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
        <input type="number" v-model:value="num1">
        <input type="number" v-model:value="num2">
        <input type="number" :value="sum">
</div>
```